# Facing issues when creating multiple threads and trying to limit the number of thread

Tags: multithreading, rust

```rust
fn get_location_list(seed_info: &SeedInfo) {
    let mut handles = vec![];
    for (start, range) in &seed_info.seeds {
        let begin = *start as i64;
        let end = (start + range) as i64;
        let (sender, receiver) = channel();
        let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
            let mut loc_seed_info: SeedInfo = receiver.recv().unwrap();
            let tmp_list: Vec<i64> = (begin..end).collect();

            loc_seed_info.loc_list.push(*tmp_list.iter().min().unwrap());
        });
        handles.push(handle);
        sender.send(seed_info.clone()).unwrap();

        if handles.len() >= 3 {
            for handle in &handles {
                handle.join().unwrap();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code `handle.join().unwrap();`, I am facing the below error:

- `*handle` moved due to this method call
  move occurs because `*handle` has type `JoinHandle<()>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

I want to create multiple threads but want to limit it to 3. I expect the above code to create maximum of 3 threads and throttle at that count.

**Note**: I understand when the for-loop iteration is less than 3, handles size will not reach 3. I tried to put another for-loop outside the existing for-loop but it simply didn't work. For my problem, the for-loop size will always be >3.

Comment: You probably want to use a [thread pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool).